# Is there a native .NET implementation of the Stanford NLP libraries?

Tags: .net, stanford-nlp

I am aware of the [IKVM-based port of the Stanford NLP libraries to .NET.](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Stanford.NLP.CoreNLP/)

However, I'd like to know if there is somewhere an implementation that's an actual *rewrite* of these libraries that utilizes the .NET-native types, features and idioms and does not have a dependency on IKVM or OpenJDK. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) is a C# *rewrite* of [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/). However, the last commit is Feb 11, 2007 and, per [this comment](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/discussions/440333), the project seems to be inactive and without native alternatives. In fact, per [this review](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/releases/view/1200#ReviewsAnchor), the author has passed away.

[Stanford.NLP.NET](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET/) is a *port* of [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/) (actually .jars recompiled to .dlls using IKVM) with assemblies available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Stanford.NLP).

I'm currently working on an NLP solution in C# and think I will go with [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) builds of one of these Java libs, simply because they come from respectable groups and seem quite active:

- [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/)

If you absolutely must have native .NET, it's a perfect opportunity to start an OSS project! I'd contribute!

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was about to do - I just wanted to make sure I'm not starting something that already exists.

Comment: T.Chatzigiannakis I would be willing to contribute if you already have an open project. Working around all the Java specifics that don't 'quite' work in IKVM is getting painful.